# String comparison on cell array of strings with Matlab Coder

Tags: matlab, code-generation, string-comparison, matlab-coder

I am trying to use the MATLAB Coder toolbox to convert the following code into C:

```
function [idx] = list_iterator(compare, list)

idx = nan(length(list));
for j = 1:length(list)
    idx(j) = strcmp(compare, list{j});
end
```

`list` is an N x 1 cell array of strings and `compare` is a string. The code basically compares each element of `list` to `compare` and returns `1` if the two are the same and `0` otherwise. (I'm doing this to speed up execution because N can be quite large - around 10 to 20 million elements.)

When I run `codegen list_iterator` in the Command Window, I get the following error:

> Type of input argument 'compare' for function 'list_iterator'
>   not specified. Use -args or preconditioning statements to specify
>   input types.
>
> More information
>
> Error in ==> list_iterator Line: 1
>   Column: 18
>
> Code generation failed: View Error Report
>
> Error using codegen

I know I'm supposed to specify the types of the inputs when using `codegen`, but I'm not sure how to do this for a cell array of strings, the elements of which can be of different length. The string `compare` can also have different lengths depending on the function call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `coder.typeof` to specify variable-size inputs to `codegen`. From what I've understood of your example, something like:

```matlab
>> compare = coder.typeof('a',[1,Inf])

compare = 

coder.PrimitiveType
   1×:inf char
>> list = coder.typeof({compare}, [Inf,1])

list = 

coder.CellType
   :inf×1 homogeneous cell 
      base: 1×:inf char
>> codegen list_iterator.m -args {compare, list}
```

seems appropriate.

If you check out the MATLAB Coder App, that provides a graphical means of specifying these complicated inputs. From there you can export this to a build script to see the corresponding command line APIs:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/generate-a-matlab-script-to-build-a-project.html?searchHighlight=build%20script&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Note that when I tried this example with `codegen`, the resulting MEX was not faster than MATLAB. One reason this can happen is because the body of the function is fairly simple but a large amount of data is transferred from MATLAB to the generated code and back. As a result, this data transfer overhead can dominate the execution time. Moving more of your code to generated MEX may improve this.

Thinking about the performance unrelated to `codegen`, should you use `idx = false(length(list),1);` rather than `idx = nan(length(list));`? The former is a Nx1 logical vector while the latter is an NxN double matrix where we only write the fist column in `list_iterator`.

With your original code and the inputs `compare = 'abcd'; list = repmat({'abcd';'a';'b'},1000,1);` this gives the time:

```matlab
>> timeit(@()list_iterator(compareIn, listIn))

ans =

    0.0257
```

Modifying your code to return a vector scales that down:

```matlab
function [idx] = list_iterator(compare, list)

idx = false(length(list),1);
for j = 1:length(list)
    idx(j) = strcmp(compare, list{j});
end

>> timeit(@()list_iterator(compareIn, listIn))

ans =

    0.0014
```

You can also call `strcmp` with a cell and char array which makes the code faster still:

```matlab
function [idx] = list_iterator(compare, list)

idx = strcmp(compare, list);

>> timeit(@()list_iterator(compareIn, listIn))

ans =

   2.1695e-05
```